# Calculating number of holidays taken in a selected period

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I need to calculate the number of holidays people have taken within a given date range, but I've got no idea where to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines of using :

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Holidays, XLOOKUP(P5,H$5:N$5,H$6:N$14),
     _StartDate, DATE(G$2,E$2,C$2),
     _EndDate, DATE(G$3,E$3,C$3),
     SUM((_Holidays>=_StartDate)*(_Holidays<=_EndDate)))
```

---

Using `BYROW()` one can spill the output using one single formula as well:

```
=BYROW(P5:P11,LAMBDA(x,
 LET(
     _Holidays, XLOOKUP(x,H5:N5,H6:N14),
     _StartDate, DATE(G2,E2,C2),
     _EndDate, DATE(G3,E3,C3),
     SUM((_Holidays>=_StartDate)*(_Holidays<=_EndDate)))))
```

---

Or instead of using `XLOOKUP()` one can use `FILTER()` as well:

```
=BYROW(P5:P11,LAMBDA(x,
 LET(
     _Holidays, FILTER(H6:N14,H5:N5=x),
     _StartDate, DATE(G2,E2,C2),
     _EndDate, DATE(G3,E3,C3),
     SUM((_Holidays>=_StartDate)*(_Holidays<=_EndDate)))))
```

---

Basically it is one line of formula, I have tried to break it down into segments to show some clarity:

```
=LET(x, FILTER(H$6:N$14,H$5:N$5=P5),SUM((x>=DATE(G$2,E$2,C$2))*(x<=DATE(G$3,E$3,C$3))))
```

---

**Explanation:**

- Extract the list of holidays using `XLOOKUP()` or `FILTER()`
- Then compare it with the `From:` and with `To:`
- Finally do a sum of the products using `SUM()` function.

---

Comment: I'm getting a #NUM! error in the result cells though....any ideas?

Comment: @PaulStewart may you need to change the cell reference or ranges, that may something which may be not numeric, you may read the [MSFT_Docmentations_here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-num-error-f5193bfc-4400-43f4-88c4-8e1dcca0428b)

Comment: @PaulStewart can you tell me what issue was that. It will help me to understand as it is working on my end?

Comment: You were correct...I hadn't changed the cell references properly. All good now. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @PaulStewart glad to know it worked, btw i have not downvoted your last question.